# Selecting Rows in pandas Dataframe based on condition doesnt work

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a "Timestamp" column like this:

```
df[Timestamp]

0            1.341709
1            1.343688
2            1.344503
3            1.344593
4            1.344700
              ...    
1263453    413.056745
1263454    413.056836
1263455    413.056945
1263456    413.057046
1263457    413.057153
Name: Timestamp, Length: 1263458, dtype: float64
```

Now i have two variables to define a start and end of an interval like so:

```
start = 10
end = 15
```

To select all rows in the Dataframe where the Timestamp lies between "start" and "end" I use a query approach:

```
df_want = df.query("@start <= Timestamp < @end")
```

This gives me a Typeerror though

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'type'
```

Why does this not work, shouldnt Timestamp be of type 'float64'? Why is it just 'type'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
df_want = df[df['Timestamp'].between(start,end)]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Any idea, why a normal query approach doesnt do it?

Comment: I am not familiar with this method in python

Comment: @L.argio It somehow confuses your `Timestamp` column name with `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`, hence the error. If you change your column name to, say, `timestamp`, it should work. I'm not sure if there is any escaping mechanism for this in the `query`.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Yes, changing the column name fixes it and query method works. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

With the variables

```
df[(df['Timestamp'] >= start) & (df['Timestamp'] <= end)]
```

With the values harcoded:

```
df[(df['Timestamp'] >= 15) & (df['Timestamp'] <= 30)]
```